# Having issues with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am in ruby 2.2.3 and tried to run a bundle update.  The error I am getting is

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot   continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I cannot seem to run rspec.

Comment: read the error message :)

Comment: I've done that and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information about your environment.

Comment: I am working on Mac OSX Sierra.

Comment: So have you run `gem install nokogiri`? Is there an error? If so, add that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to download nokogiri again and it seems to be working.

Comment: so you nevertheless did what the error message stated - you made sure, that `nokogiri` is installed correctly ;)